# Automorphism of m-torsion subgroup of an elliptic curve determines the automorphism of the entire elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

> For $m\ne2$ I want to show that if two automorphisms coincide on $E(m)$, which is the $m$-torsion subgroup of the elliptic curve $E$, then these automorphisms are the same.

The statement is very simple and intuitive, but I really can not make any real progress. I guess this should be related with the structure of E(m), which I do know, but I can not do any thing meaningful.

Comment: how much of Silverman have you read?

Comment: @oxeimon Oh, I am doing 3.12, which ask to do this directly, but not from theorem in section 10. So I am just finding a way......